# Cannot understand how does Arduino memory work for program code

Tags: arduino, memory, capacity

I am using Arduino Lilypad and Uno. At first, I've developed my code and ran it on the UNO because its easier to use, but after that I've uploaded it to the Lilypad and it worked too. The intersting point is that the code is about 19-20  KB and the Lilypad's Flash memory is only 14-16 KB!
How is this possible?

The arduino IDE also allowes for maximum of about 30 KB for Lilypad and about 32KB for UNO. Where did those numbers come from? the UNO has this capacity in its Flash, the Lilypad doesn't!

Comment: Maybe it's compressed or excrypted in a certain way that the arduino can read it

Comment: Are you confusing the size of your source code with the size of the object code? Also, the size of a hex file will be more than 2x the size of the binary data that it represents.

Comment: Where did you find/see those numbers "19-20kB", "14-16kB" "30kB" and "32kB"? I mean, you must have read them somewhere as you obviously didn't just think them up yourself.

Comment: I got the numbers from arduino website. others from the arduino IDE when i upload the code. I think it's compression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Assumption**: The developed code mentioned in the question is not a very advanced and sophisticated application, and does not contain large amounts (10s of kilobytes) of data / arrays.*

---

The Arduino code size limitations apply to the final compiled binary of the application, **not the source code size**, and **not the size of the HEX file** generated from the source code. As @DaveTweed has pointed out, Hex files will be more than twice the size of the actual binary bytes that need to be written into the MCU's Flash memory. Source code files will, further, be many times the Hex file size, depending on code specifics, commenting and coding style.

A 20-kilobyte binary output would typically represent a fairly sophisticated, complex application on an Arduino / LilyPad - or, an application incorporating a large amount of data arrays or data buffers. The *source code* for such an application could well be in the 100s of kilobytes!

Even the more complex of the sample applications that come with the Arduino IDE, for instance, compile to just around 2-5 kilobytes of binary output.

---

- `UNO has this capacity in its Flash, the Lilypad doesn't!`

About [Arduino LilyPads](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardLilyPad): These are built around lower power *but not lower memory specification versions of the **same** microcontrollers* used in the Arduino Uno: The [ATmega168V](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8025.pdf) or the ATmega328 <sup>(**#1**)</sup>. Hence, the available flash memory on the LilyPad is the same as on the **corresponding** Uno board.

- `Where did those numbers come from?`

The Arduino IDE's support for ~30 kilobytes of application binary stems from the support for the [ATmega328](http://www.atmel.com/Images/8271S.pdf) family of microcontrollers on both the boards mentioned. The ATmega328 has 32 kilobytes of Flash memory, of which **the Arduino bootloader takes somewhere between half and a couple of kilobytes**, depending on which variant is loaded.

The remaining **30-odd kilobytes** (ATmega328) of Flash are thus available for user-created Arduino applications, their data, buffers et cetera.

Besides this, 1 - 2 kilobytes of SRAM and 0.5 - 1 kilobytes of EEPROM are also available on the ATmega168 and ATmega328 controllers respectively.

---

<sup>(**#1**)</sup> *While the Arduino Lilypad official page mentions an ATmega328V microcontroller, the Atmel web site does not yield (for me, anyway) any such variant of the ATmega328, on a search. Hence, no datasheet found either.*

Comment: Probably should be ATmega328PV